# catch MySQL trigger signals in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, error-handling, triggers

I want to create a MySQL trigger to generate different signals and based on those signals I want to display some specific messages through my C# code.

If I set signals like:

```
signal sqlstate '45000' //An error signal which halts my code
```

I can catch these signals in try catch bock and even find the number of MySQL exception but it  is giving me same number for various sqlstates like I tried 45000, 42000, HY000, 42S02 etc

```
catch (MySqlException y)
{            
      Response.Write(y.Number.ToString());
      // All (45000, 42000, HY000, 42S02) printing same number
}
```

Moreover, this thing halts my further code that I want to do inside the trigger.

What I want to do is, based on certain condition I just want the trigger to send some signal messages so that I can display some message through C# and the trigger should continue to work on further statements and send signals.

for example:

```
begin
        declare quan int;
        select qoh from products where pid = NEW.pid into quan;

        IF (NEW.qty > quan) THEN
            signal sqlstate 'xxxxx' /*appropriate signal number 1*/
            set message_text = 'Display message 1';
        END IF;

        IF (col2 > col1) THEN
            signal sqlstate 'yyyyy' /*appropriate signal number 2*/
            set message_text = 'Display message 2';
        END IF;
        .
        .
        .
end
```

I also tried `signal sqlstate '01000'` but my catch statement in C# is not catching it (I assume because its not an exception/error signal rather a warning).

Please help me with:

1. Appropriate signal to set that doesn't halts my trigger's further code.
2. How can I catch these different signals in C# to display different messages.

or any workaround will also be appreciated.
Many Thanks.

Comment: I just found how can I send different error number through MySQL  
`SIGNAL sqlstate '45000'` 
`SET message_text = msg, mysql_errno = 1001;`  

this `mysql_errno` I can catch in C# but this can be read in catch block/some exception only. So I have to use error signals like 45000 but if I use a non error signal like 01000 I couldn't catch it in catch block. How can I read the `mysql_errno` in C# if I use some `signal sqlstate` which doesn't halts my trigger code (like 01000)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no special mechanism in MySQL. But try these work arounds:

1. Set signal state 01000, and then check result of SHOW WARNINGS query.
2. Use [UDF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function-udf.html) to run a code from shared library. Find examples in documentation and in the internet.

Comment: SHOW WARNINGS will show last messages from current session; if you will run it from sessions where INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements was called, then you will see warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get warnings from a trigger that completes successfully; MySQL doesn't preserve them. It's been mentioned in the MySQL bug tracking system at least a couple of times (see [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55850) and [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68770)):

> This is not a bug. SQLSTATE '01xxx' indicates a warning and warnings
>   are not preserved at the end of trigger execution according to the SQL
>   standard.

As an alternative, you can try setting a variable or temporary table within your trigger and checking for it later:

```
SET @wrning = "This is a warning";
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trigger_warnings (msg VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO trigger_warnings (msg) VALUES ('This is a warning.');
...
SELECT @wrning;
SELECT * FROM trigger_warnings;
```